# Spring boot webapp values not showing up in html page from controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

OK this has to be an easy one for someone who is experienced but I am just not seeing it. Trying to return a value from the controller back to the screen. All I ever get is "${user.email}" to show up in my input field.

```html
 <input  type="email" class="form-control" name="email" disabled=true value=${user.email}>
```

My java controller below. Debugging it i verified values are all there and nothing is missing as the "credentials" object are coming from another screen. The screen renders fine to the "loggedIn" screen but the input field(above) as it passes the "exists" check. Why wont the email render on the input field?

```
@Controller
```

public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedIn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loggedIn(Credentials credentials, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    ScraperMqSQL aDb = new ScraperMqSQL();
    boolean exists = false;
    try {
        User aUser = new User();
        aUser.setUSer(credentials.getUserName());
        aUser.setEmail(credentials.getUserName());
        aUser.setPassWord(credentials.getPassWord());       

        mv.addObject("user", aUser); 
        model.addAttribute("user", aUser);
        exists = aDb.doesUserExist(aUser);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(exists) {
         mv.setViewName("loggedIn");
    }else {
     mv.setViewName("notify");
    }
    return mv;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf or JSP? (Use Thymeleaf if you have the option. Also note that you're much better off just letting that `SQLException` escape from your controller; `printStackTrace()` does not work with logging systems politely and won't help you explain to your user what's going on.)

Comment: using Thymeleaf and it is an html page if it matters

Comment: @vsek, I hope that you solved your issue. But If not, you can try to check tag form if you put the object : `<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${user}" th:action="/loggedIn" method="post">`  . An then, you can use the input email like this : `<input  type="email" class="form-control" name="email" disabled=true value=${email}>`   . Normally, we use `${user.email}` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible because you are using this.

```
aUser.setEmail(credentials.getUserName());
```

You should set email here.

Answer (score 0):

Since Thymeleaf is built in such a way that you can view and edit the HTML templates as plain HTML, you must identify to the Thymeleaf engine when you want it to perform replacement. In this case, `value` (as most HTML tags) is simply used as-is. If you want Thymeleaf to insert a dynamic value, use `th:value` or `data-th-value`.